# Google Analytics Segments w/ Conditions: Boolean order of operations?

Tags: google-analytics, advanced-segments

Using Google Analytics, I'm trying to create a "supported browsers" segment using the Conditions section, but the boolean order of operations isn't occurring as expected. A simple example is below.

[image]

`AND` usually takes precendence over `OR`, so I'd expect my segment above to be interpreted as `(Safari AND v10) OR (Chrome AND v57)`, which would allow me to include a number of Browser/Version combinations.

However, it seems like that's not the case, here. I believe this because:

1. My results zero out with the segment configured as pictured, but if I remove either the first or fourth clause, I'll get results. This is consistent with my filters being interpreted as `Safari AND (v10 OR Chrome) AND v57`, such that `Safari AND (v10 OR Chrome)` and `(v10 OR Chrome) AND v57` both return results.
2. The horizontal line by each `AND` operator seems to divide the clauses as described above.

`OR`-precedence doesn't make any sense to me, since the "Add Filter" button already allows the user to add additional clauses which would be equivalent to an `AND`, allowing the user to choose `OR`-precedence if they needed to. As it is, there seems to be no way to construct an `AND`-precedent segment.

Comment: Yes, you're right. According to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments#combining-filters OR operator has a higher precedence.

Comment: Oh! Great resource, @jakub.kowalik. However, I didn't see operator precedence mentioned on that page. I'm also looking at this page (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments-feature-reference#combining-conditions) and I don't see it there, either...

Comment: "You can combine one or more dimension conditions with AND (i.e., ';') and OR (i.e., ',') operators with OR operator having a higher precedence."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to create multiple filters so that each filter can compare the same dimension. So, for example, this type of segment would have a filter for the browser (Safari or Chrome) AND a filter for the browser version (10 or 57). This segment would show you traffic for those browsers only.

Here are screen shots of the segment and the resulting browser table:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is a clever solution. It happens to work as long as the browser ranges don't overlap. E.g. if I wanted to detect Browser X versions 5-10 and Browser Y versions 7-12, I'd be catching too many combinations with the `OR` terms. I upvoted, but will wait a bit for a complete solution. It's kind of just crazy that they designed the feature this way...