# Experiment ID and Variant - Multiple experiments

Tags: google-analytics, google-optimize

In Google Optimize I have multiple experiments running on a single website.

I want to create a segment for a specific experiment and a specific variation. Like this:

[image]

Does it include only the sessions for that specific experiment and the variant 1 from that specific experiment? E.g how does it make sure that the users from this experiment (some other variant) and another experiment's variant 1 are not included?

```
EXP1 - VAR1 & EXP2 - VAR2 = MATCH
EXP1 - VAR2 & EXP2 - VAR1 = ?
```

---

PS! This is not the same question as this one: [Google Analytics Segments w/ Conditions: Boolean order of operations?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106217/google-analytics-segments-w-conditions-boolean-order-of-operations)

That other one is about browsers, and clearly, you can't use multiple browsers at once BUT you can be part of multiple experiments at the same time!